# OrientDB ETL with JSON data file

Tags: json, etl, orientdb

I am not seeing good documentation on how to use the OrientDB ETL function to load a JSON **data** file.

I am running this command: ./oetl.sh ../template_etl.json
The contents of template_etl.json looks like this:

```
{
    "config": {
        "log": "debug"
    },
    "begin": [
    ],
    "source" : {
        "file": {"path": "../repos.json", "lock" : true }
    },
    "extractor" : {
        "row": {}
    },
    "transformers" : [
        {"json"},
        { "vertex": { "class": "V" } }
    ],
    "loader" : {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal../databases/template",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbAutoCreate": true,
            "tx": false,
            "batchCommit": 1000,
            "dbType": "graph"
        }
    }
}
```

I took this example from a csv example from https://www.udemy.com/orientdb-getting-started/#/lecture/1998370 where this line: {"json"}, was originally: {"csv": {"separator": ",", "multiValue": "NULL", "skipFrom": 1, "skipTo": 1 } },

**The Error I am getting is:**
orientdb-community-2.0/bin$ ./oetl.sh ../template_etl.json

```
OrientDB etl v.2.0 (build @BUILD@) www.orientechnologies.com
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Error on unmarshalling JSON content for record: "config": {
        "log": "debug"
    },
    "begin": [
    ],
    "source" : {
        "file": {"path": "../repos.json", "lock" : true }
    },
    "extractor" : {
        "row": {}
    },
    "transformers" : [
        {"json"},
        { "vertex": { "class": "V" } }
    ],
    "loader" : {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal../databases/template",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbAutoCreate": true,
            "tx": false,
            "batchCommit": 1000,
            "dbType": "graph"
        }
    }

    at   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.fromString(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:304)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordAbstract.fromJSON(ORecordAbstract.java:165)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.fromJSON(ODocument.java:1712)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.main(OETLProcessor.java:147)
    Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Error on unmarshalling JSON content: wrong format ""json"". Use <field> : <value>
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.fromString(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:181)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.getValueAsRecord(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:595)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.getValueAsObjectOrMap(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:565)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.getValue(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:413)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.parseCollection(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:677)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.getValueAsEmbeddedCollection(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:659)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.getValueAsCollection(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:638)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.getValue(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:415)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerJSON.fromString(ORecordSerializerJSON.java:249)
        ... 3 more
```

I'm hoping there is a way to load a JSON **data** file directly into OreintDB.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The json is not valid. Try to validate with www.jsonlint.com. Try replacing:

```
{"json"},
```

With:

```
{"json": {} },
```

Comment: Thanks Lvca.  That json validator is a great tool.  Through the validator I am getting an error.  Says it's expecting a string.  So I am still checking my json.

Comment: So now have valid json thanks to your help, Lvca.  Now I am getting saying the database engine was not specified, but I am using plocal.                                                                                                         
Exception in thread "main"  Error on creating ETL processor
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error in database URL: the engine was not specified. Syntax is: <engine>:<db-type>:<db-name>[?<db-param>=<db-value>[&]]*. URL was: plocal../databases/template

Comment: after plocal you should use :

Comment: Ahhh, when I read the original example I assumed that only applied to Windows since the example was C:.  Thanks.  That worked.  It created a database and began processing the json data file.  I am further down the path, but have an exception "ETL process halted...Found invalid class name. Character ':' cannot be used in class name."  I had no issues loading this json data file in Mongo so I assume it is valid.  It's too big to load into the json validator.  I appreciate your help so far.  If you have any ideas, I would appreciate it.

Comment: The exception is "Found invalid class name. Character ':'", so I guess it's trying to create a class with ":" in the name. Could you share the piece of json with that error?

Comment: {
    "config": {
        "log": "debug"
    },
    "begin": [
    ],
    "source" : {
        "file": {"path": "../prod_repo.json", "lock" : true }
    },
    "extractor" : {
        "row": {}
    },
    "transformers" : [
        {"json": {} },
        { "vertex": { "class": "V" } }
    ],
    "loader" : {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:../databases/rmtemplate",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbAutoCreate": true,
            "tx": false,
            "batchCommit": 1000,
            "dbType": "graph"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Could you post your input JSON that gives this error? If it's big, please use Gist.

Comment: I took a smaller subset of that big JSON data file and ran it though the json validator and it came back as valid.  I then ran the ETL command and still get that colon error.  I redacted the data in the following json file.  The structure is the same.  So here is the etl.json and then I'll give you the data json file.  Both come back as valid through the json validator.

Comment: {
    "config": {
        "log": "debug"
    },
    "begin": [
    ],
    "source" : {
        "file": {"path": "../nfl.json", "lock" : true }
    },
    "extractor" : {
        "row": {}
    },
    "transformers" : [
        {"json": {} },
        { "vertex": { "class": "V" } }
    ],
    "loader" : {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:../databases/nfl",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbAutoCreate": true,
            "tx": false,
            "batchCommit": 1000,
            "dbType": "graph"
        }
    }
}

Comment: {
    "AFC": [
        {
            "team": "Pittsburgh Steelers",
            "division": [
                "afc",
                "North"
            ],
            "record": [
                "11-5",
                "4-2"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "NFC": [
        {
            "team": "Green Bay Packers",
            "division": [
                "nfc",
                "North"
            ],
            "record": [
                "12-4",
                "5-1"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "NFL": "NORTH"
}

Comment: Try using no class in vertex transformer:  { "vertex": {} }

Comment: Still getting exception.  Looking through documentation.            OrientDB etl v.2.0 (build @BUILD@) www.orientechnologies.com
BEGIN ETL PROCESSOR
[file] DEBUG Reading from file ../nfl.json
[0:json] DEBUG Transformer input: {
[0:json] DEBUG Transformer output: {
[0:vertex] DEBUG Transformer input: {
[0:vertex] DEBUG Transformer output: v({)[#11:0]
[1:json] DEBUG Transformer input:     "AFC": [
Error in Pipeline execution: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSchemaException: Found invalid class name. Character ':' cannot be used in class name.

Comment: Could you send to me the piece of input file and JSON cfg to reproduce locally?

Comment: {
    "config": {
        "log": "debug"
    },
    "begin": [
    ],
    "source" : {
        "file": {"path": "../nfl_divs.json", "lock" : true }
    },
    "extractor" : {
        "row": {}
    },
    "transformers" : [
        {"json": {} },
        { "vertex": {} }
    ],
    "loader" : {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:../databases/nfl",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbAutoCreate": true,
            "tx": false,
            "batchCommit": 1000,
            "dbType": "graph"
        }
    }
}

Comment: {
    "AFC": [
        {
            "team": "Pittsburgh Steelers",
            "division": [
                "afc",
                "North"
            ],
            "record": [
                "11-5",
                "4-2"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "NFC": [
        {
            "team": "Green Bay Packers",
            "division": [
                "nfc",
                "North"
            ],
            "record": [
                "12-4",
                "5-1"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "NFL": "NORTH"
}

Comment: I also simplified with this:    {
    "AFC": "North",
    "AFC": "South",
    "AFC": "East",
    "AFC": "West",
    "NFC": "North",
    "NFC": "South",
    "NFC": "East",
    "NFC": "West"

}

Comment: Following the OrientDB-Manual.pdf, page 1027, I changed the extractor from "row" : {} to "json" : {}, and now I get a different error.  Slow progress.    "...OExtractorException: [JSON extractor] error on extract json....SerializationException: Error on unmarshalling JSON content for record: "AFC":"...

Comment: Try to embrace the input json file with [].

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert like Lvca but your source file has a json extension. Which means your extractor must be replaced with ("json": {}) and there are no "json" transformers.

```
"extractor" : {
    "json": {}
},
"transformers" : [
    { "vertex": { "class": "V" } }
],
```

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Transformer.html